# Read XML over HTTP in vb.net in a Windows (10) Universal App

Tags: xml, vb.net, http, win-universal-app

I'm figuring out how I can read an XML over HTTP in vb.net in a Windows (10) Universal App. I've already tried several possbilities, but I can't get any of them working. Someone who can help me?

Greetings

edit: I already managed to get my xml code in a XDocument. Anyone knows how i can further read in it and take certain items out of it?

```
    Dim xml As String = String.Empty
    Dim url As New Uri(Convert.ToString((link)))
    Dim httpClient As New HttpClient()
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml")
    Dim response = Await httpClient.GetAsync(url)
    Using responseStream = Await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()
        Using streamReader = New StreamReader(responseStream)
            xml = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
    End Using
    Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)
```

Comment: Is the webpage an xml page?  if yes then you can simply use XDocument.Load(URL).  If this doesn't work then I recommend you use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  You can download xml using an IE then compare sniffer results with your vb.net code.  I would compare the http headers with two methods and find differences.  Make your application look as much like the IE results as possible.

Comment: What do you mean of read XML over HTTP? A Http request with a XML return result?

Comment: @sunteen I've got a http webpage with plain xml in.

Comment: @jdweng I've tried 
Dim doc As New XDocument
doc.Load(link)
But I get the error: Cannot open 'link'. The Uri parameter must be a file system relative or absolute path.

Comment: Try like in your code using Convert.ToString(link).  Not sure why in your code you are using two sets of parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have aleady get your xml code in a XDocument, and I don't have your xml, suppose we have got the xml like following:

```
<Root>
    <Father>
        <Child1>data1</Child1>
        <Child2>data2</Child2>
    </Father>
</Root>
```

And next we need read a certain item. We can read the nodes by using XElement class.
For example get a node named `Father` from your `xDoc`

```
Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)    
Dim root As XElement = xDoc.Root
Dim Fathernode As XElement = root.Element("Father")
```

Same as the the sub node

```
Dim childnode As XElement = root.Element("Father").Element("Child1")
```

These will get the whole node. If you only want to get the value of the node,
using

```
Dim value As String= root.Element("Father").Element("Child1").Value
```

More details please reference [XElement Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx).

Comment: The problem is I have an xml with same tag names like below:
<root>
  <hotels>
    <hotel>
       <location>.....</location>
       <name>.....</name>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
       <location>.....</location>
       <name>.....</name>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
       <location>.....</location>
       <name>.....</name>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
       <location>.....</location>
       <name>.....</name>
    </hotel>
</hotels>
</root>

Comment: @Boaz You can use ` Dim root As XElement = srcTree.Root
        Dim hotelnodes = root.Element("hotels").Elements("hotel").ToList ` to get the collection and then to deal with them by foreach and so on. If you need frequently to location the node you can use another way [Xpath](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301220). If you still cannot resolve, give the detail and exactly requirements and ask me to give a full demo. By the way if you think my answer helped you ,could you please give a mark?