# vb.net how to remove headers and footer from HTTP 1.1 response

Tags: xml, vb.net, httpresponse, tcpclient

I'm obtaining this response using a TcpClient:

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 3644
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------------------7e13971310878
Host: 192.168.1.103:123
User-Agent: cpp-httplib/0.9

---------------------------7e13971310878
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AE31172988786444323443"; filename="anpr.xml"
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 3417

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EventNotificationAlert version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.isapi.org/ver20/XMLSchema">
<ipAddress>192.168.1.64</ipAddress>
<ipv6Address>::</ipv6Address>
<protocol>HTTP</protocol>
...
</EventNotificationAlert>

---------------------------7e13971310878--
```

I'm interested in keeping only the xml part, so I'm trying to get rid of headers and footer. I don't know in advance all the content of the response, so I need a generic solution not based on string replacement or such.

With this I get rid of the headers:

```
Dim HTTPHeaderDelimiter As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & vbCrLf
If dati.IndexOf("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>") > -1 Then
    dati = dati.Substring(dati.IndexOf(HTTPHeaderDelimiter) + HTTPHeaderDelimiter.Length)
End If
```

But I have some doubt on what is the best way to remove the footer also, meaning the "---------------------------7e13971310878--" any idea?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use TcpClient over HttpClient to retrieve the XML? Like [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901128/read-xml-over-http-in-vb-net-in-a-windows-10-universal-app)?

Comment: @HelO'Ween no specific reason, I just used the code from another old project, I'll try with HttpClient, Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

I just added this before the end if

```
dati = dati.Substring(0, dati.IndexOf(vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "-"))
```

Seems ok, but I wondering if there are smarter solution to manipulate the raw response string